# 5 year moving average

Tags: sorting, time-series, stata

Here's the problem,

I currently have cross-sectional data with many people born the same year(from 1876 to 1971), I created a dummy that will take 1 if the obs went to university, a dummy on the location of the individual and the sex. Now, I would like to know what is the average schooling by year born and make a graph for each region and sex by year. Then, I need to smooth the graph with a 5 year moving average. I was wondering if some

I tried with this code but it does not work:

````
generate SCL = 0 
replace  SCL = 1 if educca > 13

 
// Loop to calculate the mean education for each birth year
forvalues year = 1876 to 1971 {
    // Filter the data for the current birth year
    keep BY == `year'
    
    // Calculate the mean education for this birth year
    egen mean_education_`year' = total(SCL)
    
    // Replace missing values with 0
    replace mean_education_`year' = 0 if missing(mean_education_`year')
}

// Display the results
list BY mean_education_*, noobs

// Create a 5-year moving average graph
tsset BY
tsline mean_education, ma(5) ///
 title("5-Year Moving Average of Mean Education") ///
    xlabel("Birth Year") ylabel("Mean Education") ///
    ytitle("Mean Education")```
````

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. You are more likely to get help if you describe how your code does not work. Do you get an error? Does it generate unexpected results etc.

Comment: You should ask specific problems, not present a dump of much of your code without a reproducible example or any statement of what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data example here but I can see various serious problems, the first of which would stop the code. Let's first simplify

```
generate SCL = 0 
replace  SCL = 1 if educca > 13
```

to

```
generate SCL = educca > 13
```

while flagging that any missing values on that variable would be treated as more than 13.

Now to the first crunch.

```
// Loop to calculate the mean education for each birth year
forvalues year = 1876 to 1971 {
    // Filter the data for the current birth year
    keep BY == `year'
    
    // Calculate the mean education for this birth year
    egen mean_education_`year' = total(SCL)
    
    // Replace missing values with 0
    replace mean_education_`year' = 0 if missing(mean_education_`year')
}
```

confuses calculation of the mean with calculation of the total, but that is not a fatal error as far as Stata is concerned.

One fatal error is that the `keep` syntax is wrong. You need an `if`. If you fix that, the next fatal error I spotted is that second time around the loop you have no observations with `year` 1877 because the previous `keep` threw them out.

You don't need a loop at all, but if you want means by region and sex as well as year you must include those variables in the calculation. Also, there is no point in creating a new variable for each year, which won't make anything easier. The whole loop could be replaced by

```
egen mean_education = mean(SCL), by(year region sex)
```

except that when we get to the next block of statements, we will see that you will be better off with something else.

The next block of code is also confused. First, the `tsset` won't work because you don't have a dataset with just one observation per year. (You don't explain whether `BY` and `year` are the same, or different.) Note that the `list` would have been futile even if your previous code worked, as you were trying to create 96 new variables, and you can't `list` 97 variables comfortably. Then the syntax just supposes that `tsline` allows an option `ma(5)`.

````
// Display the results
list BY mean_education_*, noobs

// Create a 5-year moving average graph
tsset BY
tsline mean_education, ma(5) ///
 title("5-Year Moving Average of Mean Education") ///
    xlabel("Birth Year") ylabel("Mean Education") ///
    ytitle("Mean Education")```
````

I will back up. Forget `egen` although it calculates your means. You would be better off with something like

```
collapse SCL, by(region sex year) 
egen panel = group(region sex), label 
tsset panel year 
tssmooth ma SCL5=SCL, window(2 1 2)
```

and then you have both means and smoothed means for each region and sex. Whether that will fit comfortably on one graph I won't try to guess.

Where did this code come from? If you used AI, it's evidently a time waster.

Note: Necessarily I can't test anything here.

Note 2: Binomial weights 1 4 6 4 1 / 16 are a better idea than equal weighting.